# multi-multi point pgrouting functions

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I have two point layers, X layer and Y layer, with nearest node on a road network calculated for each.

I wish to calculate the shortest path from X nearest node to Y nearest node. I do not want matching shortest distance X-Y pairs and wish to specify that X nearest node is the start point with Y nearest node (shortest distance) being end point to calculate the distance between them?

Are there multi-multi pgrouting functions which enable user to specify such?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 new "cost-matrix" functions in the latest pgRouting release, which are currently marked as "proposed" but supposed to be stable: http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/src/costMatrix/doc/costMatrix.html#costmatrix

Not sure this was, what you are looking for.

Comment: So i want to be able to specify the start_vids and end_vids from differing tables using their nearest_nodes (obtained from road_network). No luck so far with costmatrix.